# Git Rebase Conflict: Who is HEAD?

Tags: git, meld

I have this project where the remote repo has the main development branch, and I have a fork containing the experimental branch. I'm required to `rebase` changes from the development branch to my experimental branch before I push to my fork. So it goes like:

```
git checkout experimentalbranch
git fetch remoterepo
git rebase remoterepo/developmentbranch
```

By this time, I hit conflicts. However, *I'm not familiar with any of these changes* (I'm rebasing weeks worth of changes, because they didn't merge my changes immediately). Also, it's my first time doing `rebase`. I'm more accustomed to `merge`.

In meld, it usually is like `<<LOCAL||REMOTE>>` for `merge`, which sounds very intuitive. But in `rebase`, it's `<<HEAD||COMMIT MESSAGE>>`. Who is `HEAD`? Is it the `HEAD` of the development branch? Is it the latest code in the development branch or somewhere else?

Answer (score 150, accepted):

#### TL;DR (added May 2018)

The whole thing is fundamentally at least a little bit confusing because Git lets its internal workings show right through to you.

Note that the cases we are concerned with here occur when you run:

```
git checkout somebranch; git rebase origin/their-branch
```

or similar.  The rebase has halted temporarily to force you to resolve a merge conflict, after which you're supposed to `git add` the resolved conflict and run `git rebase --continue`.  (If you use some merge tool with `git mergetool`, or a fancy GUI interface, that interface may do some or all of this for you some other way, but underneath, it's `git add`ing the resolved files and running `git rebase --continue`.)

At the very beginning, the `HEAD` commit is *their* branch, so that if you use `git checkout --ours` or `git checkout --theirs`, `--ours` means *theirs*—the final commit of `origin/their-branch`—while `--theirs` means *yours*, the first commit you're rebasing.  This is the normal everyday sort of Git confusion (see [What is the precise meaning of "ours" and "theirs" in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25576415/1256452)) and is not what led to the original question.

Later, however, the `HEAD` commit is actually *a kind of mixture*.  It's the *result of copying some number of your commits atop their latest commit*.  You're now getting a conflict between your own partly-built *new* series of commits, and your own *original* commits.  The source of this conflict is *usually* something "they" did (something that changed along the way in `origin/their-branch`).  You still have to resolve this conflict.  When you do, you may see the very same conflict recur in later commits.

Again, `HEAD` or `local` or `--ours` is *a commit that rebase has built by combining your changes and their changes*, and the other commit (`remote` or `>>>>>>>` or `--theirs`) is your own commit, which rebase is trying to copy atop `HEAD`.

#### Longer

When merging (including rebasing, which is a special case of repeated "merging" internally), there are two "heads" (two specific branch-tips) involved.  Let's call these `your-branch` and `origin/their-branch`:

```
              G - H --------      <-- HEAD=your-branch
            /               \
... - E - F                   M   <-- desired merge commit [requires manual merge]
            \               /
              I - J - K - L       <-- origin/their-branch
```

This point is commonly (and unsurprisingly) confusing, although when labeled like this it's clear enough.

Making it worse, though, git uses `--ours` and `--theirs` to refer to the two head commits during a merge, with "ours" being the one you were on (commit `H`) when you ran `git merge`, and "theirs" being, well, theirs (commit `L`).  But when you're doing a rebase, the two heads are reversed, so that "ours" is the head you're rebasing on-to—i.e., their updated code—and "theirs" is the commit you're currently rebasing, i.e., your own code.

This is because rebase actually uses a series of cherry-pick operations.  You start with much the same picture:

```
              G - H           <-- HEAD=your-branch
            /
... - E - F
            \
              I - J - K - L   <-- origin/their-branch
```

What git needs to do here is to *copy* the effect of commits `G` and `H`, i.e., `git cherry-pick` commit `G`, then do it again with commit `H`.  But to do that, git has to *switch* to commit `L` first, internally (using "detached HEAD" mode):

```
              G - H           <-- your-branch
            /
... - E - F
            \
              I - J - K - L   <-- HEAD, origin/their-branch
```

Now it can start the rebase operation by comparing the trees for commits `F` and `G` (to see what you changed), then comparing `F` vs `L` (to see if some of your work is already in `L`) and taking any changes not already in `L` and add it.  This is a "merge" operation, internally.

```
              G - H           <-- your-branch
            /
... - E - F                   G'   <-- HEAD
            \               /
              I - J - K - L   <-- origin/their-branch
```

If the merge does not go well, `HEAD` is still left at commit `L` (because commit `G'` does not yet exist).  Thus, yes, `HEAD` is the head of their development branch—at least, it is right now.

Once the copy of `G` exists, though, `HEAD` moves to `G'` and git attempts to copy the changes from `H`, in the same manner (diff `G` vs `H`, then diff `F` vs `G'`, and merge the results):

```
              G - H           <-- your-branch
            /
... - E - F                   G' - H'   <-- HEAD
            \               /
              I - J - K - L   <-- origin/their-branch
```

Again, if the merge fails and needs help, you're left with `HEAD` pointing to `G'` instead of `H'` as `H'` does not yet exist.

Once the merges all succeed and commits `G'` and `H'` *do* exist, git removes the label `your-branch` from commit `H`, and makes it point to commit `H'` instead:

```
              G - H
            /
... - E - F                   G' - H'   <-- HEAD=your-branch
            \               /
              I - J - K - L   <-- origin/their-branch
```

and you are now rebased and `HEAD` is once again what you would expect.  But during the rebase, `HEAD` is either their branch-tip (commit `L`), or one of the new commits copied and appended past their branch-tip; and `--ours` means the branch being grown at the end of `L` while `--theirs` means the commit being copied-from (`G` or `H` above).

(This is basically git exposing the raw mechanism of *how* it does what it does, which happens rather a lot in git.)

Comment: So basically `HEAD`, in the very first operation is "their-branch"'s `HEAD`, and in the succeeding operations, `HEAD` is now the newly appended commits from me?

Comment: Yes; but it can be quite confusing because they're newly-appended-commits on the branch you're "growing", which has no name yet.  In the drawings above, they're on the middle row, rather than the top or bottom row.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. my boss gave me this glare when i explained that i got confused with what HEAD was. i think he lives in the rebase universe and i lived in the merge universe.

Comment: Reading this I am still unsure when I encounter a `<<<<<<< HEAD` in a conflicted file whether that bit is mine or theirs? Does the complexity of the answer mean it can be paraphrased as "It depends"?

Comment: @dumbledad: yes, it depends on whether you are doing `git merge` or `git rebase` (or, for that matter, `git cherry-pick` or `git revert`).  In all cases `HEAD` is whatever was `HEAD` when the actual command ran, so the most confusing one is that `git rebase` runs `git cherry-pick` (for interactive rebase) or `git am` (for non-interactive) from a detached HEAD that is growing new commits on the target.

Comment: If while I'm stopped at a rebase conflict I use HEAD in a git command, is that the same HEAD as the HEAD in the current conflict markers?

Comment: I guess that's not my real question. What I really want to know is which commit introduced the changes in the HEAD side of the conflict.

Comment: @nafg: This is tricky.  Suppose, for instance, that rebase has already successfully copied the first three (out of four total) of your commits: then `HEAD` is the copy of your third commit. The merge conflict is a result of copying your fourth commit. But obviously your fourth commit applied just fine in the *original* series of four. Where did the conflict come from? It must be from some earlier (ancestor-of-`HEAD`) commit: not one of your three that are so-far copied, but something before that point. But it could be anywhere.

Comment: Right, that's why I amended my question. But git knows (or can); couldn't it tell me?

Comment: @nafg: That's not exactly true: Git *doesn't* know which commit introduced that; it's just looking at raw snapshots (hence the conflict points to `HEAD`). You can run `git blame` to have Git find an earlier commit that touched the line(s) in question. Note that this just finds the *latest* commit that touches those lines; earlier commits may still be the primary source of the conflict (e.g., perhaps Joe's commit touches the lines, reformatting them slightly, but Indira's commit before that put in a major change and is the one you should look at).

Comment: @torek that's technically true, but that's just a broader point about git; in the same way maybe Indira was actually moving code that Mike authored in some other file. Or repo. Git doesn't operate at that level. It's lower-level than that. But it is what it is. In git terms, I would say the latest commit that touches those lines is all that matters. So I would absolutely be very grateful if git were to show in the conflict marker the latest commit that is to `blame` for that version.

Comment: Perhaps another dimension is that a conflict side has multiple lines which can have different blame commits, and maybe it's not always easy to define which is "latest" (if they're from different parents of a merge)? Then again you could elect the merge commit...

Comment: @nafg: The way to find out in general is to run `git blame` on whichever commit contributed the input that you're curious about. But even then `git blame` is imperfect: it has to do a linear walk back through history, while history isn't necessarily linear. It uses a heuristic across merge commits to pick whichever side seems more promising, for that file. Note that `git blame` *does* look for merged and copied code; it's pretty good at finding things in most real cases.

Comment: This answer is good, but could be better with a TL;DR entry at the top.

Comment: @torek Lol! : )

Comment: @torek Clearest explanation on rebase yet! Other sources skip the merging part make it seem like rebase doesn't do merge at all. All that fastforwarding stuff...

Comment: Can I get a TLDR of the TLDR?

Comment: @DavidvanDugteren: "It's confusing"? :-) (Perhaps even "inherently confusing"...)

Comment: The diagram made by another poster in another Stackoverflow thread is the TLDR I needed.

Comment: This is just great. It all makes perfect sense now, at least in the limited scope I need it to make sense in. Thanks.

Comment: `theirs` means `ours`, while `yours` means `theirs`. Got it....and how many programmers does it take to rebase a branch?

Comment: @BenKoshy: only one, but they really have to want it first?

Comment: Great answer! "...But to do that, git has to _switch_ to commit `L` first, internally (using "detached HEAD" mode): ..." -> Is this what the [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#:~:text=If%20%3Cbranch%3E%20is%20specified%2C%20git%20rebase%20will%20perform%20an%20automatic%20git%20switch%20%3Cbranch%3E%20before%20doing%20anything%20else.) is talking about? (_"If `<branch>` is specified, `git rebase` will perform an automatic `git switch <branch>` before doing anything else."_) Also, why is it a detached HEAD? The HEAD points to the same commit `L`, as the `origin/their-branch` does.

Answer (score 9):

## Definitions

*In this section we are going to see the deficiones that we are asked in response:*

> Who is HEAD?

**`HEAD`**: **the current commit your repo is on**. Most of the time HEAD points to the latest commit in your branch, but that doesn't have to be the case. 
`HEAD` really just means "what is my repo currently pointing at".

In the event that the commit `HEAD` refers to is not the tip of any branch, this is called a "**`detached head`**".

> Is it the HEAD of the development branch?

At the moment in which a merge or rebase is made the `HEAD` **immediately passes to point to the created or refactorized commit** and *therefore will be pointing to the development branch*.

In `git bash` we can see the`HEAD` situation, listing commit:

```
# Normal commit list
git log
# List of commit in a single line
git log --oneline 
# All commits graphically-linear (Recommended as alias)
git log --all --graph --decorate --oneline
```

## Practice

*In this section we will see the _how_ works some actions performed by the user*

When the user proceeds to :

```
# Command to change from the branch to the current one to experimentalbranch
git checkout experimentalbranch
# Command that traverses the typical workflow to synchronize its local repository with the main branch of the central repository (remoterepo)
git fetch remoterepo
# git fetch origin
# git fetch origin branch:branch
# With the command git rebase, you can take all the changes confirmed in one branch (remoterepo), and reapply them over another developmentbranch
git rebase remoterepo/developmentbranch
```

> By this time, I hit conflicts. However, I'm not familiar with any of these changes (I'm rebasing weeks worth of changes, because they didn't merge my changes immediately). Also, it's my first time doing rebase. I'm more accustomed to merge.

The union of branches is done in two ways:

- git merge
- git rebase.

*Note* :

*For the examples we will use the following tree* :

```
* a122f6d (HEAD -> remoterepo) Commit END
* 9667bfb Commit MASTER
| * b9bcaf0 (origin/experimentalbranch, experimentalbranch) Commit 3
| * 110b2fb Commit 2
| * e597c60 Commit 1
|/
* 0e834f4 (origin/remoterepo) First commit
```

#### git merge

The best known form is `git merge`, which performs a fusion to three bands between the last two snapshots of each branch and the common ancestor to both, creating a new commit with mixed changes.

For example :

```
git checkout remoterepo
git merge experimentalbranch
```

It would produce us :

```
*   003e576 (HEAD -> remoterepo) Merge branch 'experimentalbranch' in remoterepo
|\
| * b9bcaf0 (origin/experimentalbranch, experimentalbranch) Commit 3
| * 110b2fb Commit 2
| * e597c60 Commit 1
* | a122f6d Commit END
* | 9667bfb Commit MASTER
|/
* 0e834f4 (origin/remoterepo) First commit
```

#### git rebase

`git rebase` basically what it does **is to collect one by one the changes confirmed in one branch, and reapply them on another**.

Using rebase can help us **avoid conflicts whenever it is applied to commits that are local and have not been uploaded to any remote repository**. 
If you are not careful with the latter and a partner uses affected changes, sure you will have problems since **these types of conflicts are usually difficult to repair**.

For example :

```
git checkout remoterepo
git rebase experimentalbranch


* f8a74be (HEAD -> remoterepo) Commit END
* 4293e9d Commit MASTER
* b9bcaf0 (origin/experimentalbranch, experimentalbranch) Commit 3
* 110b2fb Commit 2
* e597c60 Commit 1
* 0e834f4 (origin/remoterepo) First commit
```

> What is origin?

`origin` : **the default name that git gives to your main remote repo**. Your box has its own repo, and you most likely push out to some remote repo that you and all your coworkers push to. That remote repo is almost always called origin, but it doesn't have to be.