# How to always give preference to the stashed version in any merge required by `git stash pop/apply`?

Tags: git

I'm looking for the "moral equivalents" of

```
% git stash pop --theirs
```

and

```
% git stash apply --theirs
```

...where the hypothetical<sup>1</sup> `--theirs` flag stands for: *"whenever a merge is required, always accept the stashed version"*.

What's the simplest way to achieve the same effect?

Also, for the sake of completeness (although I've never needed it), I'd be interested in knowing how to achieve the equivalent of

```
% git stash pop --ours
```

```
% git stash apply --ours
```

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Curiously, `git` has no objection to the `--theirs` flag shown above, though it is not documented in the man page for `git-stash`, so I don't know what it's supposed to do, if anything.  Whatever this is, it does not resemble the description of *my* "hypothetical" `--theirs` flag above.</sup>

Comment: Ours and theirs are a thing in Git. They're used to name the branches when merging as far as I know. I can't wrap my head around it however and I don't think it is really worth the trouble. You can read this post to get started: [What is the precise meaning of “ours” and “theirs” in git](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25576672/5185571). Note that the flags `--ours` and `--theirs` exist at least for checkout. Finally, if git detect conflicts, you surely need to do the merge manually so that you don't completely break your code.

Comment: @Awildelephant: thanks, but I am fully aware of the significance of `--theirs` and `--ours` in the context of `git` commands; this is precisely why I chose those particular flags for this question.  The fact remains that those flags are not mentioned in the documentation for `git-stash`, and in my experience, `git` is not very forgiving when it gets flags in a context it does not expect.

Comment: I have no idea what `git` has to do with morality... I would posit that `git` is pretty much a-moral (not the same thing as immoral).

Comment: @twalberg: you might generally (and validly, I think) object to this as abuse of language :-)  but I'll note that the phrase "moral equivalent" is nopw not uncommonly used in a context where morality is irrelevant, e.g., https://ultimaker.com/en/community/view/10516-service-manual-or-moral-equivalent-thereof-for-um2-in-particular-how-to-reattach-the-filament-driver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `git stash` script was not good about complaining about unknown flags.  This was improved in [commit d6cc2df5c80dc4f52a56679baa5e32539eb028b1](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/git/git.git/commit/?id=d6cc2df5c80dc4f52a56679baa5e32539eb028b1) (tags suggest this was first officially part of git as of v2.4.4).  If you don't have that version, the `--ours` and `--theirs` arguments are just quietly ignored.

In the case of `apply` and `pop`, the script calls `git merge-recursive` directly, but never passes on flags.  You could copy the script and edit it to add the ability to pass on `-X` and arguments.  (To see the script git is running for you, look at `$(git --exec-path)/git-stash`.)  It may be a bit trickier than that, though, since applying a stash means applying both the index version (the revision specified by the stash ID) and the work-tree version (that commit's second parent).