# Force checkout of the file after conflict from stash

Tags: git, git-merge-conflict

I did `git stash save` then `git pull` `git stash pop` and now I have conflicts and I want to reset one file to be the same as from pull to remove changes from stash (I have other changes in other files that I wan to keep).

I've tried:

```
git checkout -f inst/app/server.R
```

but got warning:

```
warning: path 'inst/app/server.R' is unmerged
```

and the file is unchanged, I still have conflict markers inside. How can I checkout that file from last commit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:** It sounds like you want `git checkout --ours inst/app/server.R`.

You are in the middle of a conflicted merge, so there are *two* "last commit"s.  One is your HEAD (current) commit.  Note that your current commit is the one you were on when you ran your command, unless your command is `git rebase`, in which case things get swapped around: see [What is the precise meaning of "ours" and "theirs" in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25576415/1256452)  Since you say the last command, the one that failed with a merge conflict, was `git stash apply`,<sup>1</sup> your current commit is the one you made after your `git pull` ran a successful `git merge` for you,<sup>2</sup> and the other commit is one of the several commits in your current `git stash` [stash-bag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20409853/1256452) under the name `stash@{0}` (aka just `stash`).

(There is a third commit involved in any conflicted merge, which is the *merge base*.  It's probably less relevant for stashes, which are a bit weird, but it is worth mentioning.  Note that if you set `merge.conflictStyle` to `diff3` in your Git configuration, you will get the merge-base version with an extra set of conflict markers, `|||||||`, between the `<<<<<<<` and `>>>>>>>` sections showing you the "ours" and "theirs" versions.  I like to keep `diff3` set, as it shows me what was there before I-and-they both changed the file in conflicting ways.)

When you run `git checkout` without either naming a specific commit, or using the `--ours` or `--theirs` option, Git tries to get the version from the index.  (Remember, the index—also called the *staging area* and sometimes the *cache*—is where you are building the *next commit you will make*.)  But a conflicted merge leaves *three* versions of each conflicted file in the index.  Git doesn't know which one to get, so it fails with that error.  Using `--ours` tells `git checkout` to copy the "ours" (i.e., HEAD) version of the file from the index to the work-tree; using `--theirs` tells `git checkout` to copy the "other" (i.e., MERGE_HEAD) version of the file.<sup>3</sup>

When you do extract one of these version from the index, that leaves the other two versions in the index, i.e., leaves the file in unresolved-merge state.  *Inspect the contents carefully* to be sure you have the correct version, then `git add` the file to resolve the conflict.  This will wipe out the three separate index versions, putting the work-tree version into the "resolved" index slot (slot zero).

If you need to re-create the merge conflict, you can use `git checkout -m -- path` (the `--` is only required if the *`path`* resembles an option, but it is a good habit to get into).  This works up until you run `git commit` to finish the failing merge.

Once everything is resolved the way you want, use `git commit` to finish the merge.

---

<sup>1</sup>You said `git stash pop`, but `git stash pop` is just a shortcut meaning "Run `git stash apply` and then, if and only if that succeeds, run `git stash drop`."  Since the apply step failed, you will have to run `git stash drop` manually, once you are satisfied that the stash has applied cleanly and been committed.

<sup>2</sup>I recommend avoiding `git pull`.  All it does is run two other Git commands for you: `git fetch`, then either `git merge` or `git rebase` depending on what you tell Git in advance.  It's better to run the two commands separately, so that:

- you know what is failing, when one fails; and
- you can choose merge or rebase *after* inspecting what `git fetch` fetched.

There's nothing fundamentally wrong with using `git pull`, just remember that it's really `git fetch && git something`, and you have to decide the "something" part ahead of time.  If you don't pick one, Git will pick `git merge`, which is probably the wrong default, but is what Git first did, way back in 2005, and therefore cannot be changed. :-)

<sup>3</sup>There is no `--base` option, but you can use [`gitrevisions` syntax](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) to access it from the index: `git checkout -- :1:path`.  You can use this same syntax to get at the `--ours` version, which is index entry #2, and the `--theirs` version, which is #3, but it's easier to remember `--ours` and `--theirs` anyway.

The "ours" version is sometimes called the *local* version, and the "theirs" version is sometimes called the *remote* version, but I hate these names.  "Remote" in particular is much too easy to confuse with remotes like `origin` and remote-tracking branch names like `origin/master`.