# difference between git merge ours theirs commands

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, gitlab

I am practising GIT. Whats the difference between below commands?

```
git merge -s ours branch

git merge -s theirs branch

git merge -X ours branch

git merge -X theirs branch
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the precise meaning of "ours" and "theirs" in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25576415/what-is-the-precise-meaning-of-ours-and-theirs-in-git)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I've already read such threads, but didn't understood clearly. Can you able to explain differences in simple language with some example (if possible)

Comment: The [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/merge-strategies) explains it well.  `-X ours` does a merge but favors the current branch's version in case of conflicts.  In case of no conflict, it would allow changes from the other branch.  The `-s ours` merge _strategy_, on the other hand effectively ignores other changes besides the current branch.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen so when exactly I have to go for -s or -X ?, sorry some what confusing concept..

Comment: That depends on what you want to do.  `-s ours` seems to blindly take our version during a merge.  `-X ours` just gives preference to our version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before I start this answer, let me emphasize that there are two different words that are both spelled "merge".  There is a verb form, *to merge*, which means "to combine changes".  There is a noun or adjective form, *a merge* or *a merge commit*, which refers to a specific kind of commit.

The `git merge` command usually does both: it *merges* (verb) some changes, and then makes *a merge* (noun) or *a merge commit* (adjective).  Git has many ways to do the verb form of merge, though.  It also *allows* the `git merge` command to omit the final noun form merge (but we'll ignore this case entirely here).

#### Strategy or extended option—the short version

The short version is that you almost never want the *strategy* option `-s ours`.

Using the `-X` (eXtended) options, you can tell Git to favor the "ours" or "theirs" side of a merge *in the case of a conflict*.  That is, suppose the merge base version of file `wallaby.txt` says, in part:

```
The Bennett's wallaby is
a variety of the red-necked wallaby.
```

One of the two branch tip versions—let's call this the *left side* or *local* or `--ours` version—says:

```
The Bennett's wallaby is
a smaller variety of the red-necked wallaby.
```

The other branch tip version, i.e., the *right side* or *remote* or *other* or `--theirs` version—says:

```
The Bennett's wallaby,
which is found on Tasmania,
is a variety of the red-necked wallaby.
```

When we *compare* the base version to the two branch tips, the comparisons make similar, but not exactly the same, changes to the same range of lines:

```
$ git diff $base $left
...
 The Bennett's wallaby is
-a variety of the red-necked wallaby.
+a smaller variety of the red-necked wallaby.
...
```

But:

```
$ git diff $base $right
...
-The Bennett's wallaby is
-a variety of the red-necked wallaby.
+The Bennett's wallaby,
+which is found on Tasmania,
+is a variety of the red-necked wallaby.
```

These two changes clash, and you will get a *merge conflict*.

The eXtended `-X ours` option means "prefer our change": where the two changes clash, ignore *their* change entirely, and take *ours* instead.  The eXtended `-X theirs` option means "prefer their change", i.e., ignore ours.

Note that whichever change you prefer, you will lose something here.  One change mentions that the Bennett's wallaby is a bit smaller, and other other mentions that it's the Tasmanian form.  If you pick just one, you lose the other.  You probably should combine this change manually, rather than letting Git choose one side.

#### When and why you might use `-s ours`

If this is the *only* change to the file, using `-s ours` instead of `-X ours` would not make a difference to this particular file-level merge: either way we would take "our" (left-side) change, and ignore theirs.  But suppose further that *only their version* fixes a typo elsewhere in the file:

```
 $ git diff $base $right
 ...
 -walaby
 +wallaby
 ...
```

with nothing like that in the `$left` (local or `--ours`) output.  If we use `-X ours` instead of `-s ours`, we will at least pick up this fix.  Of course, the right side might have a change that *adds* typos instead of removing them.  Git won't know or care: its job is to *combine* the changes, not to decide whether they make any sense, whether individually or combined!

Moreover, [as Tim Beigeleisen mentioned in a comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44858155/difference-between-git-merge-ours-theirs-commands#comment76697971_44858155), the `-s ours` option does not even *look at* the right-hand side diff.  In fact, it does not run any diffs at all!  It tells Git to make the merge commit without using the other side in any way.  In other words, it merely records that there *was* a merge, without actually doing any merging.

The only reason to do this is to make a commit-graph history record of the merge.  It is this history, as recorded in the commit graph itself, that determines how you and Git will "see" what happened, when you—or anyone else—come back later to look.  The presence of a *merge commit* means that you and Git will see the merge as having *already taken* all the good parts of whatever got merged—even if the method of "taking" was *ignore everything.*  Having already taken all those parts, you will never take them again: so `-s ours` allows you to "kill off" a branch, not by merely ignoring it, but by recording for all history that you *deliberately* killed it.

#### Git records only the result, not the method

Git *does not* record the merge strategy, nor any strategy options.  So the only way you can tell whether someone used such options is to guess.  If you come across some repository with some merge commits inside it, you can *repeat* the merges yourself, and see if you get the same result.  If you *do* get the same result, perhaps the person who did the merge used the exact same command you just used.  If you get a *different* result, perhaps the person who did the merge used a different command, or a different set of arguments.  Or maybe they resolved any conflicts manually!

#### More background

For more background, let me quote from my perennially-not-making-much-progress (because I have a job :-) ) book.

---

#### A high level view of merging

The goal of a merge is easy to understand. Several people or groups, or even just one person with two or more tasks, started from a common code base, and made a series of changes. For instance, in the Marsupial Maker, Alice may be working on wombats while Bob works on kangaroos. Each person or group (or even just one person taking on multiple roles) works in her or his private repository and/or private branch. These two lines of development—i.e., branches in the philosophical sense we noted in Chapter 1—are related by this common starting point. We won’t worry yet how they manage to *share* their commits, but at some point, someone—perhaps Alice or Bob, or perhaps a third person—will combine the changes. The combination should take all the good parts of both changes. The simplest method of combining is to perform the *three-way merge* from the same chapter. Now that we understand commit graphs, and have a general idea about comparing newer commits against older ones, it is time to take a brief high level look at how both Git and Mercurial perform merges.

#### Two commits and a merge base

In Chapter 2, we noted briefly (see page 38 and page 45) that the LCA of any two commits is their *merge base*. In some cases, there can be more than one merge base, but this is rare and we won’t address it yet. Instead, let’s just note that the—presumably single—merge base is, by definition, not just *a* common ancestor of two other commits. It is, in fact, *the correct* common starting point: it is the *first* commit that is reachable from both of the two heads (Mercurial) or branch tips (Git) that we are merging. The VCS needs to find the merge base to find out both *what we did* and *what they did.*

In both Git and Mercurial, we choose one of our two commits by the normal checkout process. Whatever commit we have checked out now—our *current* commit—participates in the merge. We choose a second commit using some appropriate commit-identifier, typically a branch name but occasionally a hash ID, or in Mercurial,
a simple revision number (or sometimes even nothing at all, and
the VCS figures it out for us). That will be the “other” or “theirs” commit.<sup>18</sup> We may then simply run `git merge otherbranch` or
`hg merge otherbranch`.

---

<sup>18</sup>I call the three commits *base*, *current*, and *other* here. Git has no single, consistent name for the current and other commits. Mercurial consistently calls them the *local* and *other* commits. I also refer to the two non-base commits as the *sides* of the merge. In several places, Git does call the current commit *ours* and the other commit *theirs*.
There is, however, a problem with the ours/theirs nomenclature that we will see later, when we cover cherry-picking and rebasing.