# (Git Merging) When to use 'ours' strategy, 'ours' option and 'theirs' option?

Tags: git, github, version-control, merge

Definition of **recursive** merge strategy pulled from the [git merge documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#_merge_strategies).

> This can only resolve two heads using a 3-way merge algorithm. When there is more than one common ancestor that can be used for 3-way merge, it creates a merged tree of the common ancestors and uses that as the reference tree for the 3-way merge. This has been reported to result in fewer merge conflicts without causing mismerges by tests done on actual merge commits taken from Linux 2.6 kernel development history. Additionally this can detect and handle merges involving renames. This is the default merge strategy when pulling or merging one branch.
>
> The recursive strategy can take the following options:

As stated, the recursive strategy, which is the default strategy, makes use of the 3-way recursive merge algorithm (explained [here](http://www.drdobbs.com/tools/three-way-merging-a-look-under-the-hood/240164902?pgno=1) and on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(version_control))).

My understanding is that conflicting hunks must be manually resolved and they are typically represented like this

```
<<<<<<<<<<<
developer 1's code here
============
developer 2's code here
>>>>>>>>>>>
```

The **ours** option of the recursive merge strategy is documented as follows:

> This option forces conflicting hunks to be auto-resolved cleanly by favoring *our* version. Changes from the other tree that do not conflict with our side are reflected to the merge result. For a binary file, the entire contents are taken from our side.
>
> This should not be confused with the *ours* merge strategy, which does not even look at what the other tree contains at all. It discards everything the other tree did, declaring *our* history contains all that happened in it.

Now suppose I have the heads of two branches Y and M, with a common base ancestor B as follows

[image]

When merging Y and M using the default recursive strategy, line 30 will become `Print("hello");` since at line 30, Y represents a change from the base ancestor and M does not. But if I were on branch M and run

`git merge -s recursive -X ours Y`

will line 30 become `Print("bye");` in the merged output?

To those of you who say that this is obvious, note that the **ours** option states

> This option forces **conflicting hunks** to be auto-resolved cleanly by favoring *our* version.

But (as I understand) there is no conflicting hunk at line 30.

For completeness, I will also give the documentation of the **theirs** option:

> This is the opposite of *ours*.

---

The documentation for the **ours** strategy is as follows:

> This resolves any number of heads, but the resulting tree of the merge is always that of the current branch head, effectively ignoring all changes from all other branches. It is meant to be used to supersede old development history of side branches. Note that this is different from the -Xours option to the *recursive* merge strategy.

So returning to the example above, if I ran

`git merge -s ours Y`

on branch M, it is clear that line 30 will be `Print("bye");` in the merged output. In this case, why is there also not a **theirs** strategy? How can I achieve behaviour equal and opposite to the **ours** strategy?

I'm asking because I'm working on a project where I want to regularly and completely overwrite the master branch with changes from another development branch, whenever the code on the development branch builds successfully. This way I can ensure that my development branch never drifts too far off from the master branch and also that the code on the master branch will build successfully.

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624357/how-do-i-overwrite-rather-than-merge-a-branch-on-another-branch-in-git) which recommends the solution

```
git checkout dev-branch
git merge -s ours master
```

But Git simply outputs `Already up-to-date`, despite the fact that the two branches contain different code (and `dev-branch` is actually a few commits ahead of `master`).

My current solution is to do

`git merge -s recursive -X theirs dev-branch`

I have also seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173919/is-there-a-theirs-version-of-git-merge-s-ours) which recommends using the **theirs** option of the **recursive** strategy. But as the **ours** option of the **recursive** strategy is clearly different **ours** strategy, so too would the **theirs** option of the **recursive** strategy be different from the **theirs** strategy that I'm talking about.

Comment: This question duplicates a lot of parts of a lot of other questions. Consider my answers to https://stackoverflow.com/q/42099431/1256452 https://stackoverflow.com/q/44212642/1256452 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/44858155/1256452 (maybe start with the last first?).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> `git merge -s recursive -X ours Y` will line 30 become `Print("bye");` in
>   the merged output?

No, it will also output `Print("hello");`. This is because only the other side (`Y` branch) changed this file, file version on `M` branch is the same as their ancestor `B`, so recursive merge strategy keep the updated version from `Y` branch.

And you can have try: only the file’s version from `M` branch is different from their ancestor `B` (such as commit for changing 30 line as `Print(“bye1”);`), then the `-X` options can works. Now if you use  `git merge -s recursive -X ours Y`, the output will be `Print(“bye1”);`.

And you can also find in **Figure 4** of the [article you linked](http://www.drdobbs.com/tools/three-way-merging-a-look-under-the-hood/240164902?pgno=1), if one side of the file is same as their ancestor (as line 30 and 70), the file will keep the other side (changed) version as the merge results.

> Reason for `git merge -s ours Y` output Print("bye");:

As the document said,
*This resolves any number of heads, but the resulting tree of the merge is always that of the current branch head, effectively **ignoring all changes from all other branches**.*

That means it will ignore the version from `Y` branch and only keep the version as current branch is. So you got the output as the version of `M` branch `Print("bye");`.

> Why there is no `git merge -s theirs` for -s option:

Git only defined the merge strategies with **octupus**, **ours**, **recursive**, **resolve** and **subtree**, so the `-s theirs` can’t be recognized and it’s a design issue. For the detail reason, only the git version control system developers may know.

---

For your situation (make sure `development` branch overwrite `master` branch), you can **`cherry-pick`** the latest commit from development branch to master branch with **`-X theirs`** option:

```
# On master branch
git cherry-pick development -X theirs
```

This will fully overwrite `master` branch.

**Note:** `development` in `git cherry-pick` command means the commit which `development` branch is point to (latest commit on `development` branch). You can also use commit sha-1 value instead.

Comment: Why is there not a **theirs** strategy given that there is an **ours** strategy?

Comment: Git only defined with octupus, ours, recursive, resolve and subtree merge strategies. It's a designed issue and only the git version control system developers may know the detail reason.

Comment: The cherry-picking strategy you've suggested does not seem to lead to clean merges. I still get messages of the form '`development` is X commits ahead, Y commits behind `master`'. But thanks for your help anyways.

Comment: If you want development sync with master, you can use `git merge development` after cherry-pick.