# How to make git merge use theirs not only for the conflicts but also for the unconflicts?

Tags: git

In my branch, I add a new folder with some files in it `mine_only/**`, and I modified some other files.

In their branch, they also modified some files, when I merge their branch, some files are merged, and some files have conflicts.

I need to keep `mine_only/***` but discard my other changes to above other files and use theirs only.

I find if I use `-X theirs`, only the conflicted files are theirs, my changes to those unconflicted files still remains.

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you make your question more clear?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [(Git Merging) When to use 'ours' strategy, 'ours' option and 'theirs' option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45402742/git-merging-when-to-use-ours-strategy-ours-option-and-theirs-option)

Comment: In short, you need `git merge -s ours`.

Answer (score 0):

you can checkout their branch version with

```
git checkout their-branch -- .
```

then you can checkout your changes into the working folder

```
git checkout your-branch -- my_folder/.
```

now just add all changes and commit to finish your merge.