# Git move directory from one branch to another within the same repository while preserving history?

Tags: git

How to git move directory from one branch to another while preserving history?

I want to move in the same repo.

Comment: I think This question has asked before any way this is what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41811986/git-move-directory-to-another-repository-while-keeping-the-history

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I copy a version of a single file from one git branch to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307579/how-do-i-copy-a-version-of-a-single-file-from-one-git-branch-to-another)

Comment: No in the above links they are moving from one repo to another. I wanna move from one branch to another

Comment: @shrutihegde No, in the linked question (by jpeg) they deal with branches in the same repo. I encourage you to reread it.

Answer (score 6):

#### TL;DR

You can't (quite) get what you want—but if you try sometimes, you might just find, you get what you need.

All you have to do is rename the directory and commit.  You may first need to extract the directory from the other commit, if it's not already in the commit at the tip of the current branch.  That is, you might need an initial:

```
git checkout otherbranch -- path/to/directory
git commit                                      # optional, but see below
```

and then in any case, run:

```
git mv path/to/directory new/path/to/dir
```

and then `git commit` the result.  That doesn't do what you *want*, but it might do what you *need*—especially if you make that first commit that *doesn't* have the renaming, so that you have two adjacent commits, one with the old names, and one with the new ones.

You may, instead, want to *merge* the branches, commit the merge, and only then rename and commit again.  Whether you want this, and why, requires the long explanation.

#### Long

It's important to understand two things here:

- Git stores only *files*, not directories.<sup>1</sup>  Each commit stores a full snapshot of all of the files in your project.
- Files don't *have* history, in Git.  In Git, the *commits* **are** the history.

People often object to the idea that Git stores snapshots, because `git log -p` shows *patches*, i.e., changes.  You view commit `0a36ca1`, say, and you see some change to `README.md`.  Then `git log` goes on to commit `0a36ca1`'s parent commit `922bf37`, say, and you see another change to `README.md` and/or some other files, and so on.  Doesn't that mean `0a36ca1` just stores the *changes* to `README.md`?  And the answer is: no, `0a36ca1` stores a *full copy* of `README.md` *and* all the other files.  Git *showed* changes by inspecting *both* `922bf37`—the parent of `0a36ca1`, i.e., the commit that comes just before `0a36ca1`—*and* `0a36ca1`.  Both commits have copies of *every* file.  Git compared the two commits' files.  All of the files in those two commits matched *except* for `README.md`.  Git then compared the two `README.md` versions to see what changed, and showed you what *changed* in that file.

The `git show` command is similar, except that you typically give it the hash ID of one commit, and `git show` prints the commit's metadata (who made it, when, and why—the log message) and then compares the snapshot in the parent to the snapshot in that commit.  Whatever's *different*, is what files you see.

When you ask for history with `git log` by running `git log` or `git log master`, Git:

1. Starts at the current commit (`git log`), or the *last* commit in `master`, and shows you that commit a la `git show`.<sup>2</sup>
2. Then, moves back to the parent of the commit it just showed.  This gets complicated at merge commits, but for now, just think of a nice simple linear chain.

This repeats until Git runs out of parents, or you get tired of paging through `git log` output.  Given a nice simple linear chain of commits, like:

```
A <-B <-C <-D <-E <-F <-G   <-- master
```

(the single uppercase letters stand in here for the big ugly hash IDs that Git really uses), Git starts by showing you `G` (as found by the name `master`), then moving to `F` and showing you `F`, then moving to `E` and showing `E`, and so on.  Commit `A` is the very first commit in the repository—it has no parent; there's no backwards arrow coming out of `A` to let Git move left—so `git show` shows it as having every file created from scratch.  That means `git log -p` shows it the same way.  And of course, with no parent, there's no arrow to follow backwards.

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, directories turn into internal *tree* objects, but Git won't store an *empty* directory for the simple reason that you can't get a directory into Git's index, and Git doesn't built commits from the work-tree, but rather from the index.  It's easier to think of Git as just storing files, since that's the end effect.

<sup>2</sup>This assumes you're using `git log -p`, of course.  There are several important difference between `git log` and `git show`: first, `git log` does this backwards walk; second, `git log` defaults to *not* showing a patch; and third, `git show` shows merge commits in a different default manner: `git log -p` defaults to saying to itself: *ugh, a merge commit, that's too hard: I'll just print the log message and move on, without showing a diff at all.*  The `git show` default here is to show a *combined diff*, which is a reduced form of diff against multiple parents.

---

#### `git log` can show a *subset* of history

You can, instead of just running `git log` or `git log master`, run:

```
git log master -- path/to/file.ext
```

and see what appears to be the history of `path/to/file.ext`.  What `git log` is doing here is walking *commit* history as usual, but then *not showing* some of the commits.  That is, given our simple linear chain above, `git log` starts with commit `G`.  It compares (the snapshots of) `F` and `G` to see what files changed.  If those files *do* include `path/to/file.ext`, `git log` shows commit `G`.  Then it moves back to commit `F`, even if it *showed* nothing at all.

In other words, instead of just showing you *all* the commits it walks, `git log` can show you *selected* commits from the walk.  The result is that it seems like Git has file history—but it doesn't: it's just *synthesizing* a subset history from the real history, working as it goes.

This is important because when Git is doing this synthetic file-history creation, `git log` is *modifying* the commit walk.  [The `git log` documentation calls this **History Simplification**](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_history_simplification), and it's *complicated*.  There are a half dozen or so `git log` options to control *how* history simplification will be performed.  This means that the "file history" that you see with `git log` depends on what *options* you pass to `git log`, as well as what the actual commit history is.

(Read and study the History Simplification section, at least someday, because there is a lot to it.  I've been using Git for a long time, and like to think I know a lot about it, but even then I have to refer back to the documentation for this.  In particular, the notion of "TREESAME"—which applies after subtracting away unwanted tree components from each commit—and which commits are followed at merges is especially tricky.)

#### With `--follow`, `git log` will try to detect renames

As Git is doing this commit-by-commit, backwards traversal of a chain of commits, the diff from parent to child may show that some file is *renamed*.  A file named `README` may have been renamed to one named `README.md`, for instance.  A simple:

```
git log master -- README.md
```

will show you how `README.md` evolved over time (backwards), but stop when `README.md` was named `README`, because it's looking for `README.md` and commits from here on back don't *have* `README.md`.

When you add `--follow` to `git log`, it will follow that one file—it only works with one file!—across the rename, simply by changing *which* file it's looking for.  Having detected that at, say, the commit-`D`-to-`E` boundary, the file that is now `README.md` was called `README` in commit `D`, `git log` stops looking for `README.md` and starts, with `D`, looking for changes to a file named `README`.  It's really that simple.

#### `--follow` is too simple for your use case

The problem here is that `--follow` *is* that simple, which is *too* simple.  So it won't do what you want, for two reasons:

- First, you're talking about copying files across some fairly large gap:

  ```
  ...--F--G--H   <-- master
   \
    N--O--P   <-- branch
  ```

  If your directory-full-of-files is in commit `H` on `master`, and you're just now copying it to a new commit you'll make on `branch` that comes after commit `P`, well, there's no backwards link *from* `P` to `H`.  That's why I proposed that you commit the files *without* renaming them, then rename them and commit again.  The result will be:

  ```
  ...--F--G--H   <-- master
   \
    N--O--P--Q--R   <-- branch
  ```

  where commit `R` has the files renamed, and `Q` has them not-renamed, just copied from `H`.  In the commit *log message* for `Q`, you can state that the entire directory has been copied from branch `master` at a time when it pointed to commit `H` (use `H`'s real hash ID here—run `git rev-parse master` to see what hash ID `master` specifies right now).  Then you rename the directory and commit again to make them show up as renames, whenever Git walks from commit `R` back to commit `Q`.
- The `git log --follow` option only works on *one* file.  That is, given a commit that is or descends from `R`, and therefore has the new directory name, you must run:

  ```
  git log --follow [<commit-hash>] [--] new/path/to/dir/file.ext
  ```

  which will eventually work its way to commit `R`, show `new/path/to/dir/file.ext` (because it is renamed in commit `R` as compared to commit `Q`), then move back to commit `Q` and start looking for `path/to/directory/file.ext`.

From this single detected rename, plus the log messages in `Q` and `R`, you—a smart human rather than a dumb Git program that just obeys really simple rules—can conclude that, aha, *all* of those files came from commit `H`.

This is where you *may* want a real merge.  Instead of just copying the files from `H`, you can literally make commit `Q` as a *merge commit*, connecting the history from commit `Q` back to *both* commits: `P` *and* `H`.  That is, suppose you end up with:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
 \          \
  N--O--P----Q--R   <-- branch
```

Now when Git walks through commit history, it goes: `R`, `Q`, `H`-and-`P`, `G`-and-`O`, `F`-and-`N`, and so on.  That is, `git log` walks through the actual history, one commit at a time, with a kind of complicated method of tracking through the fork in history where commits `H` and `P` merge to form commit `Q`.

The drawback to doing this merge is kind of obvious: it's a *merge*.  It will by default bring in *all* the changes since some common ancestor—since whatever commit comes before `N` and before `F` where `branch` and `master` eventually lead back to a *shared* commit: a commit that's on both branches.  You don't necessarily have to *commit* those changes, or even any changes: you can make commit `Q`'s snapshot match commit `P`'s, except of course for the new directory that you want.

(There are multiple ways to make this merge.  How to achieve it is another StackOverflow question entirely, one that's already well answered.  See [(Git Merging) When to use 'ours' strategy, 'ours' option and 'theirs' option?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45402742/1256452), and also [VonC's answer to a different question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46741538/1256452).  There are many options here but you probably would want to start with `git merge -s ours --no-commit`, if you want `-s ours` at all, and then the extraction of the files with `git checkout <commit> -- <path>`, and only then making commit `Q` as a merge.)

The advantage to the merge is that it ties the histories together, so that `git log` *can* walk from merge `Q` back to commit `H`, which is the source of actual history for the (pre-renaming) files.  The disadvantage is that it ties the histories together, so that from then on, Git believes that the *correct* result of merging `H` with `P` is `Q`, even if you later change your mind about that.

If the merge *isn't* what you want, the commit(s) plus log message(s) may be what you need.

Comment: I'm going to sing the Rolling Stones for the rest of the night and probably more. Thank you for this answer^wbook :D