# Ignoring files that are not present in the destination branch when merging a source branch into it with git

Tags: git, gitignore, conflict, merge-strategy

Hello my fellow SW developers,

I have two branches with different .gitignore files in my git repository, `develop` and `feature/my_feature`. There are files that are present in `feature/my_feature` that are not present in `develop`.
When merging the branch `feature/my_feature` back in the `develop` branch, I would like the files that are not already present in the `develop` branch to be automatically left out.

I tried the strategy proposed in the [respective chapter in the Git Book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#_merge_strategies) as well as the StackOverflow post [Git - Ignore files during merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15232000/git-ignore-files-during-merge), but the files that are missing in the `develop` branch cause a conflict to happen which is not automatically solved.

I also tried the strategy proposed in the StackOverflow post [(Git Merging) When to use 'ours' strategy, 'ours' option and 'theirs' option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45402742/git-merging-when-to-use-ours-strategy-ours-option-and-theirs-option), using the following bash script `custom-merge.sh` (which has been placed in the root directory of my repository for testing purposes) for the defined strategy `custom`:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Custom merge script to handle conflicts caused by files not present in current branch

# Check if the file exists in the current branch
if test -e "$1"; then
    # File exists in current branch, use default merge strategy
    git merge-file "$1" "$2" "$3"
else
    # File does not exist in current branch, keep file from branch being merged
    git checkout --theirs -- "$1"
    git add "$1"
fi
```

I added the strategy to my repository using the following commands:

```
git config --local merge.custom.name "Custom merge driver to handle conflicts caused by files not present in current branch"
git config --local merge.custom.driver "custom-merge.sh %O %A %B"
```

Also when trying to add the strategy to the global git config and also using the full path to `custom-merge.sh`, git returns the following error:

```
Could not find merge strategy 'custom'.
Available strategies are: octopus ours recursive resolve subtree.
```

How could I merge the branch `feature/my_feature` back in the `develop` branch while automatically exclude the files that are not already present in the `develop` branch from the merge?

**Edit 24.10.2023 08:35:**
I don't know if it's important, but I am working on Windows 10 22H2 with git 2.35.1.windows.2.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Best,
Francesco

Comment: You can just start the merge to find the conflicting files. Then, abort the merge and delete the conflicting files from the feature branch. Then, repeating the merge should work. For the future though, adopt the habit of regularly rebasing your feature branches on the target branch. This not just reveals conflicts early, it also allows testing the results of the merge before actually performing it.

Comment: The magic word is "automatically". We regularly merge our target branch into the feature branches to avoid certain conflicts. These conflicts arise, because the files are not present in the `develop`branch. And these files are needed in the feature branch, so we cannot delete them.

Comment: Okay, here's what I do in similar cases, like e.g. local configuration files: I keep those in a `local` branch as primary source. When working on a feature branch, I cherry-pick those commits into that branch. I regularly rebase that feature branch on the target branch (superiour to merging IMHO). Before merging the feature branch, I remove those commits with the configuration files from the feature branch using interactive rebasing. Maybe https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing would be worth a read, also https://github.com/RomuloOliveira/commit-messages-guide.

Comment: Thanks, but that is not what I am looking for. 
1. in our development workflow, it does not matter if we rebase or merge, since we squash the feature in the end. 
2. I am not looking for methods where I have to do stuff manually in between. I want to increase efficiency by automating it completely. That's why the method with the gitattributes (if it would work) or the method with a custom merge strategy would be perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found an acceptable solution.

Placing the following code into the `pre-merge-commit` hook deletes the ignored files prior to merging:

```
git restore --staged --worktree -- *.gitignore
git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch $(git ls-files --cached --ignored --exclude-standard)
```

---

**Explanation**

1. `git restore --staged --worktree -- *.gitignore` restores all the `.gitignore` files in the destination branch.
2. `git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch $(git ls-files --cached --ignored --exclude-standard)` deletes all the staged files present in all `.gitignore` files

---

**Drawback**

This is almost equivalent to a cleanup of the working tree, which might not be desired.