# What is "ours" and "their" while doing git rebase

Tags: git, version-control, rebase

I have applied the following commands, but have little confusion in doing rebase - what is ours and theirs in the following commands

```
git checkout app/dashboard-sprint-5
git rebase app/demandware
```

I know the current branch is `app/dashboard-sprint-5` and when i apply the rebase.

`app/dashboard-sprint-5` will be applied on the top of `app/demandware`.

What is `ours` and `theirs` in terms of branches.

I have checked the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25576415/what-is-the-precise-meaning-of-ours-and-theirs-in-git) but not satisfied

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Briefly, when we are talking about rebase, `ours` means the base branch.

So in your case `ours` will be `app/demandware`, since firstly git moves us there, and then applies changes from the `app/dashboard-sprint-5`, which will be `theirs`.

For example, here the note from [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#git-rebase--sltstrategygt) about rebase and `ours` word:

> Because git rebase replays each commit from the working branch on top of the <upstream> branch using the given strategy, using the *ours* strategy simply discards all patches from the <branch>, which makes little sense.

Comment: This is literally the first time this has made sense to me and I have being resolving conflicts for years. I always choose the wrong option but not anymore.

Comment: `ours`: the `target-branch`, `theirs`: the `current-branch` :s

Answer (score 6):

In order to easily remember the direction of *ours* and *theirs*, think of rebasing as cherry-picking each commit of the current branch onto the target branch.

```
Before rebasing:
    A--B--C (master)
       '--D--E (devel, HEAD)

Reset HEAD to master:
    A--B--C (master, HEAD)
       '--D--E (devel)

Cherry-pick D, E.
    A--B--C (master)
       |  '-- D'--E' (HEAD)
       '--D--E (devel)
HEAD becomes "ours" and the old devel branch "theirs".
              ^^^^                            ^^^^^^

On success, repoint devel to E':
    A--B--C (master)
          '--D'--E' (devel, HEAD)
```

In a non-interactive rebase that goes through without conflicts, it looks like we jump straight from the old devel-branch history to the rebased devel-branch history. In this view the inversion of *ours* and *theirs* isn't apparent, leading to potential confusion, especially also during merge conflict resolution – it is simply a bit unexpected, that the branch we started from may suddenly be called "remote branch" by merge tools.

---

Though this question was already answered, I add this more visual explanation, since I found it difficult to remember the result without.