# GIT theirs and ours, which one to use

Tags: git

I have two branches Staging and Master. All the feature branches get merged into Staging. When I want to merge Staging with Master (What I mean is I want to push Staging to 
Master and override all the conflicts).

I tried

```
git checkout master
git merge staging
```

This is where I have all the conflicts and I want override Master with Staging.
I have read about

```
git checkout --theirs .
git add .
```

But not sure if I need to use theirs or ours.

Could you guide me on how to override Master with Staging. resolve all conflicts just replace Master with Staging.

If I am doing anything wrong here do correct me.

Thanks
R

Comment: Hello, you can have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25576672/5073674
So what you want to do is 
git checkout master
git merge staging
git checkours --theirs . (to pick all from staging)
git add .

Comment: That procedure is a great way to not get the result OP specified they want.  Too bad this is marked dup or I could provide an answer that actually addresses the question.  (And no, I can't just add the answer to the other question, because it's not the same question - i.e. this is NOT a dup of that question.)

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger: oops, I'll de-duplicate (I was trying to go fast this morning...)

Answer (score 0):

```
git checkout master
git merge -s theirs staging
```

This accepts all changes from the other branch, in this case `staging`.

```
git checkout master
git merge -s ours staging
```

This accepts all changes from the current branch, in this case `master`.

Comment: [There is no `-s theirs`, though some people think there should be](https://stackoverflow.com/q/173919/1256452).

Answer (score 0):

If you want master to point to staging

Go to branch master

```
git checkout master
```

then force master to point to stagin

```
git reset --hard staging
```

that's all, but you will loose everything that is not into master
Merge and resolve fixes is the best option

Comment: I believe the OP is trying to tell git how to resolve the conflicts rather than resolving them manually.