# How Git manages an automatic solved merge?

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-branch, git-merge-conflict

I studied what is the `git merge` operation and what it does when it discovers a conflict that is not able to solve automatically.
If I can solve manually the conflicts I can choose what I want to save and what I want to change.

On the other hand we have the **fast forward** merge, if one branch is direct ancestor of the other, and on the other hand the **not fast forward** merge but automatically solved.
Here I find difficul to understand how Git treats these two cases: I've seen it selects automatically what to change but I how can I know if it's doing the things as I want?

For example on the `test` branch I worked with *file.txt* while on `master` branch I have another version of *file.txt*.
The two branches share a common ancestor.
I execute `git checkout master` and then I want to merge with `test`.
To do so I digit `git merge test`. Then what could happen?

1. `master` has a completely different content
2. `master` has text that wasn't present inside the `test` version of *file.txt*
3. `master` has fewer pieces of text than the *file.txt* inside `test`

My question concerns a generic case: How can I understand, beforehand run `git merge test`, how Git will treats these merges?
Maybe it depends on which branch I'm currently in when I start `git merge`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see if I can cover everything in a short-ish post:

- Git has multiple *merge strategies*.  When you run `git merge` you may choose a strategy, e.g., `git merge -s resolve other` or `git merge -s octopus br1 br2 br3`.  The standard strategies are `ours`, `recursive`, `resolve`, `subtree`, `octopus`, and now the new `ort`.
- Virtually all the real work is done by the strategy.  So before you can decide how a merge will operate, you must know which strategy you will be using.
- The default strategy for most merges *was* `recursive` and may soon become `ort`.  These two are mostly intended to work the same, except that `ort` should be much faster and handle a few of the tricky cases better.  (Note: that's the *goal* state, not the *current* state, which is why it's not yet the default.)  If, however, you give multiple "heads" (commits, really) to `git merge`, the default is `octopus`.

Except for the `ours` strategy (which does not need a merge base, and I think does not bother to compute one) and the `octopus` strategy (which uses an alternative merge-base computation), these merges must find the (singular) *merge base* commit.  To find that commit, Git uses a [Lowest Common Ancestor algorithm as extended to DAGs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_ancestor#Extension_to_directed_acyclic_graphs).  You can run this manually:

```
git merge-base --all HEAD otherbranch
```

for instance.  But as the presence of an "all" option implies, and the Wikipedia link makes clear, the output from this algorithm *may* be *more than one commit*.

If there is only one merge base, all is well.  If not, each strategy must do something about this.  (The octopus strategy does whatever it does since it's not using this algorithm in the first place; I've never delved all the way to the bottom of *that* question, as I am wary of <s>bugs</s> Balrogs.) The `resolve` strategy uses a straightforward but terrible answer: it picks one at (apparent) random and uses that.  The default `recursive` strategy, however, simply merges the merge bases (not using the octopus algorithm, but rather using a slightly Balrog-ridden recursive approach that `ort` attempts to improve; I wait to see the results...).

Skipping some recursive merge details (but noting that this is what the "recursive" *merge driver* entry is about), we move on: the `subtree` strategy is really just the `recursive` algorithm in disguise, so it handles these the same as `-s recursive`.  The `ours` strategy ignores all other inputs: its final commit is simply the `HEAD` commit's content, with extra parents, so merge base issues become irrelevant.  Octopus, as already noted, doesn't use `git merge-base --all` in the first place.  So if we *need* a recursive merge, the strategies that do it merge the merge bases and commit the result (*including any merge conflicts*, which is the main place a Balrog wreaks havoc on your quest).  This merged *result* is then the new merge base for the merge operation.

So, this gets us a to single merge base, either by throwing out extras (`-s resolve`) or merging them (everything else, except `-s ours` and `-s octopus`, which do not even go here).  We now have exactly three commits to consider for our merge: *B*, the merge base; *L*, the "local" or `--ours` commit; and *R*, the "remote" or "other" or `--theirs` commit.  These commits can be assumed to have some sort of precedes/follows relationship,<sup>1</sup> but it no longer matters: the various two-head merge algorithms are now ready to consider three possible cases:<sup>2</sup>

1. *B = R*.  If the merge base commit *is* the "theirs" commit, there is nothing to do.  Git says `Already up to date.` and does nothing.
2. *B = L*.  If the merge base *is* the "ours" (HEAD) commit, a *fast-forward* is possible.  If it's allowed or required, Git will do it.  Conflicts are impossible for this case; see below.
3. *B ≼ L, B ≺ R*.  A "true merge" is required.

To perform a true merge, Git does an internalized variant of the following:

- run `git diff --find-renames B L`: this is "what we changed";
- run `git diff --find-renames B R`: this is "what they changed";
- combine these changes.

The *combine changes* step is where *merge conflicts* can occur.  They *do* occur if:

- lines affected in diff #1 overlap lines affected in diff #2, but the changes to those lines are not identical, or
- lines affected in the two diffs abut (as [jthill noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69903945/1256452)).

Overlap *is* allowed if and only if the two diffs make the *same change* to those lines.

If we force a "real merge" where a fast-forward is allowed (see #2), this means *B = L*, so the diff from *B* to *L* is empty.  An empty diff never conflicts with another empty diff, nor with any non-empty diff: the result of combining is to take all of their changes.

If we *do* have conflicts, the `-X ours` or `-X theirs` flags, if specified, now come into play: these resolve the conflict by favoring ours or theirs.  For these cases, the merge is not stopped.

If we have `rerere` enabled and there are now conflicts that have recorded resolutions, Git will take the recorded resolution.  For these cases, however, the merge *is* stopped: you must inspect the result yourself.  Presumably this therefore happens *after* the `-X` cases, but I have not tested that.

If there are unresolved conflicts, the merge stops here, unfinished.  It is your job to clean up any messes left behind (in your working tree and/or Git's index).  Otherwise, unless `--squash` and/or `--no-commit` were specified, Git goes on to make the new merge commit.

If the merge stops, the other head's (or heads') hash ID(s) are written to the `MERGE_HEAD` pseudo-ref, unless `--squash` was specified.  This ensures that the next `git commit` will conclude the merge correctly.

---

<sup>1</sup>If they *didn't*, we had to supply `--allow-unrelated-histories`, in which case the merge base is a dummy empty commit that precedes both branch-tip commits.  The same code is used for cherry-pick and revert, where certain precedes/follows relationships may not hold intentionally, so it doesn't check; this description is strictly for `git merge` purposes.

<sup>2</sup>It would be possible to check *R ≼ L* up front, but I don't think Git actually does.  The effect should be the same either way.

Comment: Wow, you gave me a complete panoramic of merges.  Also I found useful another [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25576672/9766958) to understand the concepts you explained (in a fully manner) here. Now I understand why I had all these doubts about the merge, there is a world behind `git merge`!  I surely need time to fully understand your answer, however I can say that you covered the answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I understand, beforehand run `git merge test`, how Git will treats these merges?

In some rare (and basically never produced unintentionally) cases there will be additional preparatory work layered underneath the fundamental operation, or the entire thing can in the trivial "fast-forward" cases just be sidestepped, but: to see what `git merge test` will be working with, say

```
git diff ...test    # diffs on test since histories diverged
git diff test...    # diffs in checkout since test history diverged
```

and those are the two sets of diffs Git will be merging.

Git has a default automerge that applies all hunks that don't overlap or abut any different changes on the other tip, but overlapping or abutting change hunks can't be reliably automerged, no one's ever figured out how to derive a "right" general result for those so you have to sort that out.

Comment: Then if I the merge is executed in an automatic manner it means that Git won't make disasters on your code? This is my main fear when I use merge.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I understand, beforehand run git merge test, how Git will treats these merges?

You can't understand it *beforehand* but you can do the merge without actually making the merge commit and thus you can study the outcome. Just say

```
git --no-ff --no-commit merge test
```

and then look around.

Comment: Hence, to properly understand the merge operation, I need to make experiments? Are there other ways to learn how merges treats files?

Comment: Well, you could read the code. :) But seriously, if this doesn't answer your question, then I don't understand the question. Git has various strategies available to it for performing a merge of two versions of a file, and you can even add your own custom strategies. There's no single "right" answer. That's why I recommend looking to see what Git actually _does_. If you could wrap your mind around the details, you would be a computer.